# howto capture stack corruption on 64bit app?

Tags: c++, memory, crash

my 64bit app (Windows) is having a crash. I have not been able to make anything by either code examination or by examining the state in debugger. (VS2008)

with some instrumented code that performs periodic checks of the values object instance . This object that appears to be in an inconsistent state and generates an access violation when we attempt to free its members. It contains several member variables with very narrow value ranges that can serve as a test of the overall object consistency.
Thoughts? any tools that would help discover the reason?

Comment: Your question subject says its a stack corruption problem, your text says its is a heap corruption problem.  You'll need to provide a better diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the debug symbols for the executable, Visual studio gives a fairly good stack trace. If this is not sufficient, you can try to use WinDBG. It has pretty powerful stack related commands

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that your object is being double deleted and after the first delete the memory is getting reused.

You can use valgrind on Linux or Purify (For $$) on Windows to do memory checking. I believe MS also has a debug malloc library you can use, but I don't have the particulars offhand.